# Prefix JSON value - JSON/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, elasticsearch

How can I add a prefix to the payload of a JSON post request. Always prefixed with 'INC-'

Say I have

Incident: 12345

```
data: JSON.stringify({ incident: $("#incident: _name").val() }),
```

Returns
12345

What I want

Incident: 12345

```
data: JSON.stringify({ incident: $("#incident: _name") "INC-" .val() }),
```

Returns
INC-12345

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should be written like this.

Where the `$("#incident: _name").val()` part uses JQuery to select the element with ID attribute and the `.val()` is used to get the value inside the input field. then you can just concatenate `INC-` to the selector output string!

```
data: JSON.stringify({ incident: "INC-"+ $("#incident: _name").val() }),
```

Comment: Excellent Sir, I shall up vote and tick once I can, Many thanks!